# Do I need $(z-3)$ in computing my residue?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to evaluate $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z^4+1)(z-3)}$$ if $\gamma$ is the circle of radius 2 centered at the origin and travelled once in the counterclockwise direction.

Forgive me if my question is very naive but  given that $z=3$ is outside of the circle, do I have to consider the quantity $(z-3)$ in computing the residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^4+1)(z-3)}$? Better yet, can I just compute the residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4+1}$?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to consider the factor corresponding to $z - 3$ when computing residues at other poles but need not worry about the residue at $z = 3$ itself as it is outside your region of integration.

Comment: So then I can't ignore it and just do $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4+1}$?

Comment: I'm having a hard time computing the residue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also work via partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{1}{(z^4+1)(z-3)}=\frac{A}{z-3}+\frac{B+Cz+Dz^2+Ez^3}{z^4+1}$$

and then use the geometric series to get the corresponding Laurent polynomial expansion. Perhaps it is even sufficient to just multiply $\sum(\frac z3)^k$ and $\sum(-z^{-4})^k$ to get to the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: This might be the best way. I tried using a formula $\frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}$ and It's very tideous